# Update mySql table Based on jsp page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Friends i have a jsp page which retrieves data from mysql table and displays them in form of table. I will also display another column consisting of a button to give Status to 1 . i need to update the database table when i click the status button.

following is the code for jsp

```
<form action="Edit" method="post">
<table cellspacing="8">
<tr>
    <td><b>Name</b>
    </td>
    <td><b>Place</b>
    </td>
    <td><b>Gender</b>
    </td>
    <td><b>UserName</b>
    </td>
    <td><b>Password</b>
    </td>
    <td><b>Status</b>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<%
ViewService vs = new ViewService();
ResultSet rs = vs.getRecords();
while(rs.next())
{
    %>
    <tr>
    <td><%=rs.getString(2) %></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(3) %></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(4) %></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(5) %></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(6) %></td>
    <td><%=rs.getString(7) %></td>
    <td></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="userid" value="<%=rs.getString(2) %>"                                        

             style="visibility: hidden;" > <input type="submit" value="Active"></td>
       </tr>
     <%     }
     %>
     </table>
    </form>
```

And my edit servlet is

```
package Admin;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import DBcon.Dbcon;
@WebServlet("/Edit")
public class Edit extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Edit() {
    super();
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)     

throws ServletException, IOException {

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  

throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    Dbcon db = new Dbcon();
    con = db.getCon();
    int status=1;
    int userid =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"));
    try {
        ps=con.prepareStatement("update tbluser set status = ? where userid 

= ?");
        ps.setInt(7,status);
        ps.setInt(1, userid);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.sendRedirect("ViewUser.jsp");
}

}
```

Comment: so whats the problem ..if you got error then explain it so we can go through it solve it

Comment: is it that we should continue the code for u????it would be better u try and let us know when u get stuck...**Hint for your question ** use AJAX

Comment: You have mentioned what you are trying to do, please specify what problem you are facing?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

### inside while loop

put the form tag inside while loop ( < td > )  not around the < table >

```
....
<td><%=rs.getString(7) %></td>
<td></td>
 <td>
   <form action="Edit" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="userid" value="<%=rs.getString(2) %>" style="visibility: hidden;" > <input type="submit" value="Active">
    </form>
 </td>
   </tr>
 <%     }
 %>
 </table>
```

### OR

Use Hyperlink instead of form and button

```
<td>
   <a href="Edit?userd=<%=rs.getString(2) %>"> Activate </a>
<td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this bro i modified your codes.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  

throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    Dbcon db = new Dbcon();
    con = db.getCon();
    int status=1;
    int userid =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userid"));
    try {
        ps=con.prepareStatement("update tbluser set status = '"+status+"' where userid = '"+userid+"'");
        ps.executeUpdate();
        int updateQuery = ps.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.sendRedirect("ViewUser.jsp");
}

}
```